# ActiveMQ: Not enough cluster members when using LevelDB replication

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to configure ActiveMQ to use a LevelDB with two zookeeper instances on the same machine. Here is the activeMQ configuration:

```
<persistenceAdapter>

  <replicatedLevelDB zkAddress="localhost:2181,localhost:2182"

      directory="${activemq.data}/leveldb"  replicas="2"

      hostname="localhost"/>

</persistenceAdapter>
```

On the Zookeeper side, I've configured two servers with the following configurations. 
**Server 1:**

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/home/user1/z1/zookeeper-3.4.6/data
clientPort=2181
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
```

**Server 2:**

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/home/user1/z2/zookeeper-3.4.6/data
clientPort=2182
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
```

The I've created the file **myid** under the data folder containing "1" and "2" on each server. Zookeeper starts correclty and from the logs I can see that servers are discovered.
The problem is that ActiveMQ discovers just one node of the two, as indicated by this message:

```
2015-05-26 22:45:31,938 | INFO  | Session establishment complete on server example.com/127.0.0.1:2182, sessionid = 0x24d91f53ba50000, negotiated timeout = 4000 | org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn | main-SendThread(example.com:2182)
2015-05-26 22:45:32,831 | INFO  | Not enough cluster members connected to elect a master. | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.MasterElector | main-EventThread
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and found the solution at [activemq mailing list](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/ReplicatedLevelDb-Not-enough-cluster-members-connected-to-elect-a-new-master-td4669281.html)

Basically all broker nodes in activemq using zookeeper should have the same broker name.